# How to utilize jQuery to detect a change on a select tag with a dynamically-generated ID and alter options for select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

We have created a two-column HTML table on a user "profile" page generated by a web framework (Rails 4.2.x) that allows users the ability to dynamically add rows to the table (by clicking an "add row" button). Everything is working as designed. The two columns consist of two select tag dropdowns, "user_name" and "user_lunch", an example of which is here:

```
<table id="user-lunch-table">
<tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Lunch</th>
</tr>
<tbody id='user-lunch-table-body'>
    <tr class='nested-fields'>
        <td><%= f.select :user_name, @user_names %></td>
        <td><%= f.select :user_lunch, @user_lunch1 %></td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>
```

The variable @user_names consists of [ "jim", "ted" ], the variable @user_lunch1 consists of [ "chicken", "steak", "fish" ], and the variable @user_lunch2 consists of [ "salad", "tofu" ].

Due to the dynamic nature of the table (users can add rows at will), the framework automatically inserts an row-specific integer (beginning with 0) into the ID of each td within the table. For example, inspecting the table with Firebug indicates the ID assigned to the "name" column on the first row is "profile_attributes_0_user_name", the ID assigned to the same column in the next row down is "profile_attributes_1_user_name", the next row down is "profile_attributes_2_user_name", and so forth.

We have been researching for some time as to how to utilize jQuery to detect a change to the "user_name" select tag (the "Name" column) in a given row and, on change, alter the options for select in the next column over ("user_lunch, the "Lunch" column). In this case, the options for select of the "Lunch" column are set to the @user_lunch1. When the user_name dropdown is changed from "jim" to "ted" in a given row, we would like that row's user_lunch column to change the options for select from @user_lunch1 to @user_lunch2.

Given the dynamic  ID assignment, the first issue is detecting the user_name select tag change using jQuery and identifying the row on which the change occurred. Normally (if td IDs were static) we would detect the change via something like the following (please note that Rails 4.2 defaults to CoffeeScript formatting; providing a solution in standard JS formatting is perfectly acceptable):

```
$(document.ready) ->
    $('#profile_attributes_0_user_name').change(->
```

However, as the IDs are dynamic, we need the ability to determine the change using wildcards or regex.

Therefore, we need to detect a .change() for any td ID that contains both "profile_attributes_" and "_user_name". Then, we need to determine the value (0, 1, 2, etc) between "profile_attributes_" and "_user_name" to identify the row. Finally, we need to alter the corresponding "user_lunch" column on that same row, replacing the options for select from @user_lunch1 to @user_lunch2.

Thank you in advance for assistance.

Comment: Is it something related to `event delegation`?

Answer (score 3):

The method you are using to keep tabs on the various elements in your table, i.e., concatenating using the id, is a code smell. It's leading you down an overly complex path, which should make one sit up and question the idea.

A way to solve this is to simply use class names for cells to navigate to the relevant cell in the row that a select has changed, and then get the select in that cell. For example:

```
<td class="user-name"><select...></td>
<td class="user-lunch"><select...></td>
```

If the select in the .user-name cell fired, you could use this to find the row, then navigate to the select in .user-lunch:

```
$(".user-name select").on("change", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        userLunch = $this.closest("tr").find(".user-lunch select");

    //Populate userLunch select here...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. To be clear, the framework we are utilizing is automatically generating td IDs in this manner, I'm not sure it's within our control without rebuilding the entire site architecture, which may or may not be possible on this particular project due to the time-sensitive nature.

Comment: Ok, well that's a feasibility study you could do, to see if it's worth a change for long-term benefit. To deal with the code as is, however, check out jQuery attribute selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/. This was proposed in another answer, but not explained. These should help you and might obviate regex complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab your elements with this :

```
$("[id^='profile_attributes_'][id$='_user_name']").change(...);
```

then in your change, the `this` element will be the one which have changed so you can navigate and find the things you want to change